# iOS Video: More than 4 simultaneous AVAssetReaders possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, video

I would like to render multiple H264 mp4 videos on multiple views at the same time. Target is to read about 8 short videos, each at a size of 100x100 pixels and let them display their content on multiple positions on the screen, simultaneously.

Imagine 24 squares on the screen, each showing one video out of pool of 8 videos.

MoviePlayer doesn't work, for it's only showing one fullscreen video. An AVPlayer with multiple AVPlayerLayers is limited, because only *the most-recently-created Layer will show it's content on screen* (according to the documentation and my testing).

So, i wrote a short video class and created an instance for every .mp4 file in my package, using AVAssetReader to read it's content. On update, every videoframe is retreived converted to an UIImage and displayed, according to the video's framerate. Furthermore, these images are cached for a fast access on looping.

```
- (id) initWithAsset:(AVURLAsset*)asset withTrack:(AVAssetTrack*)track
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

        mOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:track outputSettings:settings];
        mReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:nil];

        [mReader addOutput:mOutput];

        BOOL status = [mReader startReading];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void) update:(double)elapsed
{
  CMSampleBufferRef buffer = [mOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

  if (buffer) 
  {
    UIImage* image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
  }

  [...]
}
```

Actually this works pretty well, but only for 4 videos. The fifth one never shows up. First I thought of memory issues, but I tested it on the following devices:

- iPhone 3GS
- iPhone 4
- iPad
- iPad 2

I had the same behaviour on each device: 4 videos playing in a smooth loop, no differences.

If it would have been a memory issue, I would have expect at least either the iPad 2 to show 5 or 6 videos (due to it's better hardware) or the 3GS to show only 1 or a crash somewhere.

The simulator shows all videos, though.

Debugging on the device shows, that

```
BOOL status = [mReader startReading];
```

returns false for video 5,6,7 and 8.

So, is there some kind of hardware setting (or restriction) that doesn't allow more than 4 simultaneous AVAssetReaders? Because, I can't really explain this behaviour. I don't think that all devices have the exact same amount of video memory.

Comment: It's more likely a limitation of the H.264 decoding chip than video memory.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am experiencing the same behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Yes, iOS has an upper limit on the number of videos that can be decoded at one time. While your approach is good, I don't know of any way to work around this upper limit as far as having that many h.264 decoders active at once. If you are interested, please have a look at my solution to this problem, this is an xcode project called [Fireworks](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#Fireworks). Basically, this demo shows decoding a bunch of alpha channel videos to disk, then each one is played by mapping a portion of the video files into memory. This approach makes it possible to decode more than 4 movies at the same time without using up all the system memory and without running into the hard limit of the number of h.264 decoder objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating separate AVPlayerItems based on the same AVAsset for each AVPlayerLayer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my latest iteration of a perfectly smooth-scrolling collection view with real-time video previews (up to 16 at a time):

https://youtu.be/7QlaO7WxjGg

It even uses a cover flow custom layout and "reflection" view that mirrors the video preview perfectly.  The source code is here:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/ivecygnlhqxwynr/VideoWallCollectionView.zip