# View multiple video and scroll horizontally IOS

Tags: ios

There is a code that allows me to view multiple videos with the option of scrolling left or right?just an example..

Thank you,

Alexander

Comment: We're gonna need more. It's very difficult to answer "What is the code" questions without knowing more about what your program is doing, what you have tried already and where you're stuck. You shouldn't be asking "Can somebody write my program". You should be asking for example "I'm having trouble deciphering a crash log, can somebody point out what I'm missing please"

Comment: I never said  "Can somebody write my program". I asked if there was a code that allows to do what a I wrote, i needed an example .. thank you for -2 ;)

Comment: Nevertheless, I wrote your program. See my answer below and, if that's not enough to get you started, feel free to contact me directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such code.
You must code this yourself.

You can achieve a similar functionality with a rotated table and some custom cells, but I'm not completely sure. It depends on how exactly you would want this to function.

For example, do you want to scroll trough a list of videos and select one of them, or do you want to scroll left or right inside a playing video and select another?

Comment: I want to scroll trough a list of videos and select one of them, i don't know what class I should use for this!

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this would be with a table, in my opinion. You make a custom cell that contains the video's thumbnail, eventually a title and/or a short description, and on didSelectRowAtIndexPath you open that video with a new controller. I guess a modal presentation would be the simplest way to achieve this

Comment: nah, because I'm working with UIImageView and i must implement in it !mmh maybe I've resolved! I will post here the source code when I finished!

Answer (score 0):

I've supplied sample code several times to questions similar to this. To see a demonstration of that code at work:

```html
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h1XOOCRrl04?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```html
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7QlaO7WxjGg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here's a link to one of my answers that may help you:

[iOS Video: More than 4 simultaneous AVAssetReaders possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060565/ios-video-more-than-4-simultaneous-avassetreaders-possible/37694977#37694977)

Search for 'AVPlayer' among my answers (in my user account) to see more.