# How to decode multiple videos simultaneously using AVAssetReader?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avassetreader

I'm trying to decode frames from multiple video files, and use them as opengl texture.

I know how to decode a h264 file using AVAssetReader object, but it seems you have to read the frames after you call `startReading` in a `while` loop when the `status` is `AVAssetReaderStatusReading`. What I want to do is to call `startReading` then call `copyNextSampleBuffer` anywhere anytime I want. In this way, I can create a new video reader class from AVAssetReader, and load video frames from multiple video files whenever I want to use them as opengl textures.

Is this doable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17138661/763355

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, you can decode one frame at a time. You will need to manage the decode logic yourself and the most simple thing is to just allocate a buffer of BGRA pixels and then copy the framebuffer data into your temp buffer. Be warned that you will likely not be able to find a little code snippit that does all this. Thing is, streaming all the data from movies into OpenGL is not easy to implement. I would suggest that you avoid attempting to do this yourself and use a 3rd party library that already implements the hard stuff. If you want to see a complete example of something like this already implemented then you can have a look at my blog post [Load OpenGL textures with alpha channel on iOS](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post7_load_opengl_textures_with_alpha_channel_on_ios/index.html). This post shows how to stream video into OpenGL but you would need to decode from h.264 to disk first using this approach. It should also be possible to use other libraries to do the same thing, just keep in mind that playing multiple videos at the same time is resource intensive, so you may run into the limits of what can be done on your hardware device quickly. Also, if you do not actually need OpenGL textures, then it is a lot easier to just operate on CoreGraphics APIs directly under iOS.